# Retrieve distinct row and declaring scalar variable

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve a distinct row from my Database from a particular "deliverySerial".

However I encountered an error which prompt me to "Declare Scalar Variable ="@deliverySerial".

I had tried many other ways but still problems still persist.

Here is the connection:

```
public class DlDbConn
{
public DlDbConn()
{

}

public SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    SqlConnection dbConn;

    dbConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

    return dbConn;
   }
  }
```

Method in the data layer:

```
    private String errMsg;
    private DlDbConn dbConn;

public testing()
{

    dbConn = new DlDbConn();
}


public DataSet Details(String supplierLogo, String supplierName, String supplierAddr, int poNum, String dateSent, int deliverySerial, String deliveryDate,
                          int quantity, String catSerial, String catName)
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    StringBuilder sql;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet detail;



    conn = dbConn.GetConnection();
    detail = new DataSet();
    sql = new StringBuilder();

    sql.AppendLine("SELECT * FROM (select PO.poNum, PO.dateSent, ViewDelivery.deliverySerial, Supplier.supplierName, Supplier.supplierAddr, Supplier.supplierLogo, ViewDelivery.deliveryDate,  Catalog.catSerial, Catalog.catName, PO.quantity, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Catalog.catSerial ORDER BY Catalog.catSerial) AS num FROM PO INNER JOIN Supplier ON PO.supplierID = Supplier.supplierID INNER JOIN ViewDelivery ON PO.poNum = ViewDelivery.poNum INNER JOIN Catalog ON PO.catSerial = Catalog.catSerial)AS a WHERE a.num = 1 ");
    sql.AppendLine("AND ViewDelivery.deliverySerial = @deliverySerial");
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql.ToString(), conn);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deliverySerial", deliverySerial);
        da.Fill(detail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errMsg = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    return detail;

}
```

Comment: Hi, i had make amendment. I had supply the parameter with " da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deliverySerial", deliverySerial);"

Comment: Your query doesn't look correct to me -- SELECT * FROM (subquery) a WHERE ViewDelivery.deliverySerial = ... ? Where are you joining ViewDelivery?

Comment: I join at here - INNER JOIN ViewDelivery ON PO.poNum = ViewDelivery.poNum

Comment: What am I missing?  Your subquery joins on that table, but not your outer queries.  Check this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5008/1

Answer (score 1):

You must use parameter notation for MySQL i.e. `?` instead of `@deliverySerial` in your query.

Also, table `ViewDelivery` not accessible in outer part of query.

Use:

```
AND a.deliverySerial = ?
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but what u mean by "?". where should i put this at?

Comment: Of course in your query. `bla-bla-bla AND ViewDelivery.deliverySerial = ?`.

Comment: but now there is another error stating that incorrect syntax near '?'

Comment: Do you use MySQL or another RDBMS?

Comment: I using MySql with microsoft visual studio.

Comment: OK, I can't find class `SqlConnection` which provide connection to MySQL server. Can you tell me what `SqlConnection` class are you use? If it from `namespase` `System.Data.SqlClient` this can't provide you connection to MySQL server. Use appropriate data access provider.

Comment: For first you must understand difference between `MySQL` and `SQL Server`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is incorrect.  Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5008/1) -- you can't query on ViewDelivery since it's outside of your subquery.

Try removing that from your WHERE criteria since that field is returned in your subquery:

```
sql.AppendLine("AND deliverySerial = @deliverySerial");
```

I don't think you need the "?", but I could be mistaken.

Good luck.

Comment: OP uses MySQL. There are more errors in the code. See comments below my answer.